# powershell get-adgroupmember is not returning groups that are from a different forest

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to display groups of an active directory security group.  I use the command

```
get-adgroupmember $group -server $serverName.
```

It doesn't return an error.  It just returns empty results.

So i tried the command

```
get-adgroup $group -server $serverName -properties memberof
```

The `memberof` section is blank.

The one thing that stands out about this security group is that they were originally from another forest.  We converted them over to the new forest with `sidhistory` in place.

The groups show up in "active directory for user and computers" gui.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose such kind of question is better of on the uservoice, since it looks like a bug.

Comment: Those two commands do two very different things. Change `memberOf` to `member` in the second example

Comment: Oh my.  You may have figured out a way I can do this.  When I change the property to member I get cn={sid key}dc=domain and they are all listed as cn=ForeignSecurityPrincipals.

I still don't know why get-adgroupmember doesn't return anything.  But I think I can at least work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Group members added as external  contacts , will always escape from get-adgroupmember .

Antidot is

`get-adgroup "groupname" -properties member | select -expand member | get-adobject`

Answer (score -1):

you are missing the -Identity

```
get-adgroupmember -Identity $group -Server $serverName | Select SamAccountName
```